# Can Extension Methods Be Called From The Immediate Window

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, code-contracts

I ask the question because whenever I attempt to call an extension method from the Immediate window in Visual Studio 2010 I get the following error:

> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If the Immediate window doesn't support extension methods, then why is it  that when I type my variable (of type `IEnumerable<QueryFilter>`) followed by a dot, the IntelliSense lists all the extension methods?

There is nothing wrong with what I am typing in the Command window because if I copy and paste it into my code file and run, it works.

With Visual Studio 2012 doing the same thing for the same solution  works fine. If I switch back to VS2010 and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992), and is not limited to just the Immediate window but also the Conditional Breakpoints window too.

**Update March 01, 2016:**
Found this [MSDN Question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9e8cec67-402f-4ac6-87be-204f2441f9f0/why-is-type-resolution-not-working-in-my-watch-windows?forum=vsdebug) asking why type resolution is not working in my watch windows. The behaviour described is exactly the same as I experience when using the Immediate Window. The cause is also attributed to CodeContracts and a bug report has been filed on Microsoft Connect. Whether or not the bug is resolve is not indicated.

Comment: Can you give some explanation why or how Code Contracts causes this problem?

Comment: No explanation. Tested it by setting up another machine, verified it worked correctly and then installed code contracts, resulting in the problem occurring.

Comment: It's not just my set-up, the exact same thing is also happening to my colleague. Running the exact same solution in Visual Studio 2012 and issuing the commands in the Immediate Window work fine. Switch back to VS2010 and the problem persists.

Comment: I don't have code contracts installed and see the same problem

Answer (score 6):

Extention methods are syntax sugar. Actually they are implemented `static` with the `this` keyword.
You can call any extention method using the static method that provides the extention method. Then you should pass the object that is being extended as the first parameter.

Comment: Why does IntelliSense list the extension methods, if I am unable to call them using that syntax? Is this a bug in Visual Studio?

Comment: Voted down because it does not answer the question as to why extensions methods cannot be called using the normal fluent notation from within the immediate window.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing thanks for explaining. However the primary question is 'can' and not 'why'. The answer is no, and I also provide a workaround. Unfortunately i cannot provide answer to the secondary why question.

Comment: while this is true, and I've been calling the methods directly from Enumerable, but this is extremely unwieldy.  calling more than one linq extension method will end up being ungodly long and a lot of type in the immediate window.  It's a bit frustrating.

Comment: This is not helpful for the case where you are pasting real code from your program

Comment: @StayOnTarget you have to convert manualy yes. It the code is to complex to modify, maybe using the intermediate window is not the best approach after all.

Comment: @Myrtle true in some cases. Watch can be used in a similar way sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

It's because the `System.Linq` namespace is not imported in the current context you are while debugging.

Add

```
using System.Linq;
```

in your code.

*Example with Visual Studio 2010*:

[image]

First times with `System.LINQ` imported, then without `using System.LINQ`.

*EDIT*:
If the namespace is imported and IntelliSense is displaying the methods, then it might be a bug of the Immediate window.
See [this bug entry on connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/598050/the-immediate-window-is-too-picky).

Comment: @Aphelion you're wrong, Immediate window **definitely does support extension methods** (just tested VS2010). At least test it before voting down -__-

Comment: @Ɖiamond ǤeezeƦ => What is the version of Visual Studio/C# you are using?

Comment: @ken2k Visual Studio 2010. AlsocI have `using System.Linq` at the top of the file I am debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Extension methods are just static methods.

You should be able to use e.g. `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList()`

Comment: Voted down because it does not answer the question as to why extensions methods cannot be called using the normal fluent notation from within the immediate window.

Answer (score 2):

The extension method translates to "Enumerable.ToList" The compiler would normally convert

```
myList.Tolist();
```

To:

```
Enumerable.ToList(myList);
```

during compile time. I believe you can use extension methods from the quickwatch window if you so wanted to.